# Is there a command line argument to bring java to front?

Tags: java, user-interface, jar, jframe, bringtofront

I have an executable jar file but no access to the code so I cannot use any method to like `myFrame.toFront();` or `myFrame.someThingElse();` to bring the window to the front.

But every time I do `java -jar something.jar` a window opens behind everything that is already on the screen so I would like to bring the GUI to the front of the screen using a command line argument.

Comment: Which OS? Windows?

Comment: Mac OSX
I was packaging the jar for both but the the problem appears to occur only to Mac users.

Comment: "*but no access to the code*" "*I was packaging the jar*" could you clarify your situation further? If you are creating the jar you must have *some* sort of access to the code being executed. You could, for instance, insert a `.toFront()` call with [bytecode manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37124239/113632) or define your own `main()` method that delegates to the existing `main()` method and uses reflection to make the calls you need.

Comment: I am not creating the jar file it is given to me so I am just trying to package it as an app for Mac